# Annotation processor for javax.annotation.concurrent.ThreadSafe and GuardedBy

Tags: java, annotations, java-threads

How can I get the annotations javax.annotation.concurrent.ThreadSafe and GuardedBy to work?
I can't find the source code of an annotation processor for `@ThreadSafe` and `@GuardedBy`.

Comment: What are you talking about? Those annotations are for documentation purposes. They don't do anything.

Comment: but the GuardedBy is not for documentation purposes,  GuardedBy  how to work?

Comment: It is for documentation purposes.

Comment: @Target( { ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface GuardedBy {
    String value();
}     not has a @Documented!

Comment: Probably because it generally documents internal implementation.

Comment: It for linting not documentation...

Answer (score 2):

The [Lock Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#lock-checker) that is distributed with the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) is an annotation processor that does compile-time checking of the [`@GuardedBy`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/lock/qual/GuardedBy.html) annotation.  If the Lock Checker issues no warnings, you get a guarantee that your program never dereferences a value unless it is holding the appropriate locks.

Answer (score 0):

The [IntelliJ](http://jetbrains.com) IDE also has inspections that look for violations of the @GuardedBy annotations.